# Unable to debug on IntelliJ on some phones

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, adb

I am unable to debug on IntelliJ one of my apps, other apps debug just fine. The issue is only happening on my Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 and on my Nexus 7 4.4.2. My GS3 with 4.3 works just fine.

The error I get is:

```
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
```

IntelliJ support says it is an issue with ddms, and I do tend to agree with them because when I open ddms by hand I can see no processes under the phones that don't work but I can see a bunch of processes under the phone that works.

Has anyone else had this issue?

IntelliJ is version 13.0.2 and I am on OSX 10.9.1

Thanks.

EDIT: I should mention I already tried restarting phone and laptop, removing the app from the phone, clearing data, clearing cache, clearing caches on intellij. Also I tried other apps yesterday and they worked just fine on all devices, so it seems to be just one app, I don't know if there is a way to clear something on ddms that it might be remembering about my app?

Comment: Before start debugging clear all apps from recent activity screen or restart the device once.

Comment: Already tried restarts, several.

Comment: have you try\ied to remove all debuggable apps from device ?

Comment: Yes, also the Galaxy Nexus I had just bought and factory reset, and this happened on the first try I'm pretty sure. The Nexus 7 I've had for a while and have tested that same app on before.

Comment: which build-tools version are you using ?

Comment: I have a 19.0.1 directory in build-tools. I am working on a chromecast app so I've been updating a lot lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when using an artifact that signs your app you must set debuggable=true on your application on the manifest.